# Version/source of Tomcat in my JBoss AS?

Tags: tomcat, jboss5.x

I am debugging a really tricky problem with servlet filters in a web application running on a JBoss 5.1.0 AS. I really need the source of the tomcat that runs inside my JBoss. I already downloaded the src-Package from JBoss but could not find the tomcat sources in it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"JBoss Web" is the JBoss modified version of Tomcat included in JBoss app servers. You can find the anonymous SVN link on [JBoss Web](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/introduction.html) page

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather like to hear about the "really tricky" problem. Post a question about that :)

Back to the actual question, you don't have much to the "original" Tomcat source. JBoss may have modified stuff here and there. They also modifies the `ServerInfo.properties` file which normally reside somewhere in the `catalina.jar` and contains the exact Tomcat version.

But, JBoss AS itself is open source as well. Why don't you just download from [there](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/)? Pick the file with `src` inside the name.